# How to show all data from list in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The problem I am having is that the recycler view is not displaying all item list. In my particular case I have 38 items and it is missing some of them. I had 34 and it was working just fine. 
I have a search bar and when I type in the ids of the missing items, it shows them. I can't find where the problem could be. Any suggestions on what to look for or changes I could make, are very welcome. Feel free to ask for any code you think is needed.

This is how I call the adapter

```
public void buildCollectionSalesAdapter(){
        final String filter = edtFindSale.getText().toString().trim();
        final SaleHeader saleHeaderModel = new SaleHeader();
        List<SaleHeader> saleHeaderList1 = new SaleHeader().getSaleHeadersAll();
        int limit = saleHeaderList1.size();
        saleHeaderList = saleHeaderModel.getSaleHeaderCollectPagination(limit, 0, filter,
                config.showVerified, config.allCustomers);
        final SalesAdapter salesAdapter = new SalesAdapter(saleHeaderList, null, context,
                CollectionFragment.this, null, getActivity());

        rcvCollection.setAdapter(salesAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(rcvCollection);

        rcvCollection.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }


            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
            {
                if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "scrolled loadin "+ loading+" "+saleHeaderList.size());
                        if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                            loading = false;
                            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + VISIBLE_THRESHOLD)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "scrolled !loadin "+ loading+" "+saleHeaderList.size());
                        // Hemos llegado al final
                        if(salesAdapter.getItemCount()>1) {
                            offset = offset + limit;
                            saleHeaderList.addAll(saleHeaderModel.getSaleHeaderCollectPagination(limit,
                                    offset, filter, config.showVerified, config.allCustomers));
                            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    // There is no need to use notifyDataSetChanged()
                                    salesAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(offset, saleHeaderList.size());
                                }
                            });
                            loading = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I found out that when I change the limit of the pagination from 10 to the list size it shows all the data.

I made it work by changing the pagination form 10 to 15, but still do not know waht is causng the error

Comment: Would be more helpful if src code is pasted

Comment: Please try to understand this topic https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

or share the source code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I will take a look at it. I posted some code

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by changing the pagination form 10 to 15, but still do not know what was causing the error.